# Как называется функция в пайтоне подобная map в arduino wiring и processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

В arduino wiring и processing, как я помню, есть функция `map()`, которая принимает значение,которое меняется пропорционально другим значениям. Например:

```
int val_out = (int)map(val_in, 0, 10, 0, 100); // если val_in = 5, то val_out = 50
```

Как называется подобная функция в PYTHON?

Comment: Что-то я такого в С++ не помню. Но простую пропорцию не написать за пару минут? Вы серьезно?

Comment: Я понял, map - функция в arduino wiring и processing. Они основаны на с++ и java, и получается я ошибся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простую пропорцию можно написать за пару минут.

Вроде бы так, если нигде в синтаксисе не напутал (python - не моё...)

```py
def map(x,a,b,c,d):
   return (x-a)*(d-c)/(b-a)+c
```